# Kotlin -How to Change Text Color of a SpannableString with an Image

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, spannablestring

I have a string with an image on the back. I'm able to change the image color to green but I can't get the text color to change to green also. It stays black.

[image]

"abc is available" should be green too

```
val span = SpannableStringBuilder()
span.append("abc is available")
span.setSpan(R.color.myGreenColor, 0, span.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
span.append("  ")

val unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkmark_icon)?.mutate()
if (unwrappedDrawable != null) {

    val wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.myGreenColor))

    val lineHeight = binding.myTextView.lineHeight
    wrappedDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, lineHeight, lineHeight)

    val image = ImageSpan(wrappedDrawable, 0)
    span.setSpan(image, span.length -1, span.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    binding.myTextView.text = span
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method shouldn't take a color resource at the first parameter, it accepts it as it's of type `Object`; but it won't have any affection.

`setSpan()` should take an object that implements [`ParcelableSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ParcelableSpan).

> `span.setSpan(R.color.myGreenColor, 0, span.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)`

So, this line of code won't have any affect; instead you'd replace it with [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan):

```
span.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.myGreenColor, null)),
            0, span.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I didn't realize that I had to use ForegroundColorSpan. Cheers :-)